# Running the iMacros Chrome plugin from Batch file

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file

I have the iMacros plugin for Google Chrome installed and I want to be able to run a .iim file from a Batch file.

I have seen many options online but they all seem to work only if you have the actual iMacros program (not just the plugin).
For example, some solutions look like:

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe imacros://run/?m=test.iim
```

Also an option that seemed to originally have worked for pluggins was:

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe http://run.imacros.net/?m=test.iim
```

But this apparently has not been working for some years now.

Are there any options to opening a iMacro file from a Batch file, only having the plugin?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on the version and OS of your computer. If you are using Windows then you might want to check to see if that version is compatable with what you are trying to do. If you are using Mac then make sure your iOS is compatable as well. Different versions of OS do different thing. For example, Windows XP batch filing does things differently than from Windows 8.1 or Windows 7.

Another example:

```
:start
Color 0a
Echo hello world.
Pause

:end
Cls
Color 0b
Echo hello again.
Pause
```

This will work in Windows 8 because it allows for color changes when cls clears the screen. However, this will not work in Windows 7, or when I tried it didn't work.